# Modify Java classes from Eclipse in running servlet?

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, ide, maven-3

I have a multi-module Maven project that is a Java web application.  I am using Eclipse as my IDE and am wondering if there is anything in WTP that will allow me to add/delete/modify Java classes without doing

- "mvn clean install" and,
- restarting the application server?

Edit:  I've seen JRebel and watched some videos, but it doesn't support CXF or GWT and it seems to me that Eclipse/WTP should do something like this out of the box, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JRebel does support CXF and GWT - refer to the features page http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/features/frameworks/

Comment: CXF is not listed on that page.  GWT is listed on the page, but the forum tells another story:   http://zeroturnaround.com/forum/topic.php?id=291

Comment: CXF is listed (the 4th from top). The forum thread is 1 year old.

Comment: You are right...must be going blind.  Given the fact that GWT has its own solution for rapid development anyway, I'll probably be giving JRebel a shot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most web containers allow you to perform hot code replacements but there are a number of limitations, such as:

- Changing the class/method signature will not work - you have to redeploy and restart
- Changing a "stack frame" call (e.g. Main) generally will not work either.

Check out [this link](http://mediocre-ninja.blogspot.com/2009/09/eclipse-wtp-hotswap.html) for instructions on how to set it up for WTP.

Answer (score 1):

Check [Dynamic Code Evolution VM](http://ssw.jku.at/dcevm/) (DCEVM). You do not need to install anything specific in eclipse. Check if it works with CXF. GWT already supports hot deployments in hosted mode, with some limitations. For example, if your server is Jboss, check [this](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/f59965939ca1aabf/beea4b6ba68f0fc9?pli=1).